# Using ASP.NET Core IServiceCollection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the ASP.NET Core 2.2 `IServiceCollection` to build the dependency injection into an ASP.NET MVC (on the full .NET Framework 4.7) app. The reason is that I have an api project built with ASP.NET Core and uses Entity Framework Core, so I want both web app (mvc) and api (core) to use the same framework (EF Core).

The problem I am having now is that `AddScoped` seems to be working as if I used `Singleton` (i.e. same `dbcontext` is being used every time I make a web request)

Can you give me a hint how to tell the `IServiceCollection` to use the ASP.NET MVC based request scope instead of the .NET Core one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using custom Scope per request:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Items.Add("serviceScope", Startup.Provider.CreateScope());
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var serviceScope = Context.Items["serviceScope"] as IServiceScope;
        serviceScope?.Dispose();
    }
```

And

```
public class DotNetCoreDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IDependencyResolver _oldDependencyResolver;

    public DotNetCoreDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, 
        IDependencyResolver oldDependencyResolver)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _oldDependencyResolver = oldDependencyResolver;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var serviceScope = HttpContext.Current.Items["serviceScope"] as IServiceScope;
        return serviceScope?.ServiceProvider?.GetService(serviceType)
            ?? _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType) 
            ?? _oldDependencyResolver.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) 
        => _oldDependencyResolver.GetServices(serviceType);
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
 Provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new DotNetCoreDependencyResolver(Provider, DependencyResolver.Current));
```